# Implementing Hough Transform

Tags: image-processing, hough-transform

I am doing a sudoku grid detection in C using SDL. I figured out that using Hough Transform could help me detect lines so I tried to implement it. However, I don't understand what to do with the accumulator array after iterating on the image.

In fact, on the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform) page, it is said that you have to apply a threshold and determine which parts of the image match the lines but I don't understand this part of the implementation.

Also, the Hough Transform implementation uses polar coordinates. However, SDL can only draw lines from two given points from what I have seen of the documentation. So how could I draw the lines with the polar expression of the lines?

PS : This is my first time using StackOverflow, I hope that I formulated my problem correctly.

Comment: Write the equations of the lines in Cartesian coordinates and find the intersections with the outline rectangle.

Comment: To detect the Hough lines, find the bins that form a local maximum configuration (accumulated value higher than those of the neighboring bins). If you are lucky, keep the N best, where N is the number of expected lines.

Comment: the right half of [this picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Hough-example-result-en.png) is literally the accumulator array. you find local maxima of a certain strength. -- I usually "find local maxima" using a combination of grayscale dilation and comparison, which gives me something very raw. then I apply some more morphology and connected components labeling to deal with various issues (equal-strength peaks closer together than set minimum distance, "peak" not being a single pixel, etc), and then filter for their value/strength (thresholding)

Comment: perhaps dive into OpenCV. https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I'll try to understand and apply it to my code.